# What is between a Major Key and a Minor Key? (keys with a neutral third)

Tags: scales, key, microtonality

I know the 2 *main* types of keys are major and minor, but is there a 3rd type of key? (Diminished keys would be extra-minor keys; so, that is not what I am searching for.)

I’m looking for keys with a **neutral third** (three and a half semitones), that are *both* more major than minor, *and also* more minor than major. These types of keys sit somewhere between major keys and minor keys. What are these types of keys called?

---

### UPDATE:

I found a *possible*, (but not exactly a definite) solution to my question.

A **melodic minor scale** sounds something between minor and major, despite the fact it is, none-the-less, a minor scale; furthermore, [Musical U](https://www.musical-u.com/learn/the-ultimate-guide-to-minor-keys/#) says:

> the [melodic minor] scale starts off sounding minor, and then switches to sounding major. This lends an interesting, conflicting quality to the scale and places it somewhere between major and minor.

Although the melodic minor scale is *not exactly* what I am still searching for, it is the closest-possible scale (that does not use quartertones or other microtones) to any non-microtonal scale sounding, and being, between major and minor.

Comment: Do you mean something like melodic minor notes rising (scale)? That has  only the 3rd as the difference between it and its parallel key? Or a key which has actually no specific m3 or M3, but something in between?

Comment: The second one: A Key which is neither minor nor Major, but something between minor and Major.

Comment: That's what a lot of Blues players (myself included) use all the time!

Comment: Cool. What is that scale called? Is it called anything other than The Blues Scale, or is that the only name for it? I always thought The Blues Scale was a Minor Scale, though.

Comment: There are two Blues scales - major and minor. But guitarists in particular, with all except minor Blues playing, will bend particularly that 3rd, often not getting here, that's in the ear of the listener!

Comment: Well, I am searching for a key that is neither minor nor Major.

Comment: If the intervals of a Scale are Unison, Major Second, {Neutral Third, (PRECISELY HALF-way between a Major Third and a Minor Third)}, Perfect Fourth, Perfect Fifth, {Neutral Sixth, (PRECISELY HALF-way between a Major Sixth and a Minor Sixth)}, and {Neutral Seventh, (PRECISELY HALF-way between a Major Seventh and a Minor Seventh)}, what is that type of Scale called? Is it called a Neutral Scale or something else? Please list precisely what it is called.

Comment: @DaveLittle - were you able to figure it out? I would love to hear your results and theory as I am searching for this answer myself. Thank you.

Comment: The desired interval may be between a minor third and a major third in pitch, but it won't be between them _in effect_.  Major and minor thirds are consonant (with approx. 4:5 and 5:6 pitch ratios); there is no interval between them with anywhere near as simple a ratio.  — Also, the melodic minor seems to be a red herring, as it uses exactly the same minor third as the harmonic minor, natural minor, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Having a third between major and minor is already departing from the traditional European pitch system.  There is no standard name for such a scale, therefore.  If you're calling the third a "neutral third," then you can call your scale a "neutral scale" by analogy with the major and minor scales, which are named after their thirds.  But since the "neutral scale" is necessarily nonstandard, it will not tell anyone much of anything about the other notes it contains.

You may also want to make up some other names in order to distinguish different scales that have that same neutral third, similar to the various types of minor scale and Dorian mode, etc.

---

I see the question has been significantly edited.  Here is a response to the original question:

> I know the 2 MAIN types of Keys are Major and minor, but is there a 3rd type of Key?

In traditional European music, no.  There are major and minor keys and there are the modes that they developed from, the Dorian, Phrygian, Lydian, and Mixolydian.  (Aeolian and Ionian were added later after modern tonality had started to develop; Locrian was added later still, primarily as a theoretical abstraction.)  Notice that two of these original modes have a minor third and two have a major third.

> Diminished Keys would be Extra-minor Keys; so, that is not what I am searching for.

Since the quality of a key is denoted by the quality of its third degree, there is not much likelihood of constructing a useful diminished key, but if you did it might start off with B, C, and D flat as its first three degrees.

> I’m looking for Keys that are BOTH more Major than minor AND ALSO more minor than Major. These types of Keys sit somewhere between Major Keys and Minor Keys. What are these types of Keys called?

You might be thinking of the four original modes; you might for example consider Dorian to be between major and minor because although Dorian has a minor third it has a major sixth.  Similarly, Phrygian has a minor second, so you might consider it more minor than minor.

But this way of looking at it does not take into account different sizes of the third; rather, it is looking at the proportion of the imperfect intervals that are minor or major.  If you want to stick to the principle of naming the key quality after the interval quality of the third degree then you are talking about different sizes of thirds and the other intervals are irrelevant.

---

In a comment you mention 24-tone equal temperament and the circle of neutral thirds.  The neutral third can be defined several different ways, and most of these yield a value very close to the 350 cents of 24-tone equal temperament.  Of course, two of those thirds equal a perfect fifth, so we can construct a circle analogous to the circle of fifths in the 12-tone system.

It's not clear what relationship this might have to the concept of keys that are somehow between major and minor.  The circle of fifths doesn't have much relationship to major and minor tonality.  I mean, a major third is four fifths minus two octaves and a minor third is three fourths minus one octave, but this doesn't extend to the circle of neutral thirds: since a fifth is just two neutral thirds, we can convert the above description of a major third to "a major third is eight neutral thirds minus two octaves," but this doesn't shed much light on anything.

The circle of fifths is mostly useful for thinking about harmonic progressions where the root is moving by fourths and fifths, not for shedding light on the nature of major and minor tonality.  The circle of neutral thirds would have intermediate steps such as A-half-flat between F and C or G-half-sharp between E and B.  But that gives us potentially interesting new pitches on which to root our chords; it doesn't give us new intervals, new chords, or new scales; these come from 24-tone equal temperament itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many more than two "types of keys."  The term you are looking for is "mode."  Major and minor are the two most common modes.  If we were to stick within the two-sharp key signature of D major, here are the most commonly-considered modes.

> D Ionian (also known as D Major)
> E Dorian
> F# Phrigian
> G Lydian
> A Mixolydian
> B Aeolian (also known as B minor)
> C# Locrian*

To play each of these start on the note indicated and play through the notes D, E, F#, G, A, B, and C#.  The second mode, Dorian, for example, would be E F# G A B C# D E.

Locrian gets a star because it begins on an unstable tone (the leading tone) and many schools of thought do not include it as a viable mode.

Comment: I’ve read about Modes, but I don’t believe Modes are what I am searching for, either. I’m searching for the name for all Keys that would consist of a NEUTRAL Third as the 3rd Scale Degree of each of them.

Comment: I think this answer would be better if you reordered the list, from "light" (majoriest) to "dark" (minoriest):  

Lydian, Ionian, Mixolydian, Dorian, Aeolian, Phrygian, Locrian

Comment: No, Modes are not what I am searching for. What I am searching for would be similar to The Circle Of Fifths, but used for 24-Tone Equal Temperament rather than for 12-Tone Equal Temperament.

Comment: Interesting you call Locrian 'starting on the leading tone'. It does start on the parent key's leading tone, but has no real leading tone of its own - its 7th note is a tone below its own tonic. (Which is why I prefer to call it 'leading *note*), as it's a semitone below, not a tone...

Comment: @DaveLittle It make a huge impact on your question that you're thinking of microtonality: specifically 24-TET. Please update your question with the details you've spread throughout the various comments.

Answer (score 1):

"Key" is an idea exclusive to the theory of Tonality, and it is reserved for Major and Minor. Those are the only two keys.

The term "key" is sometimes extended to refer to modes outside of Tonality. This is something of an abuse of the term, but usually the meaning is clear from context.

The idea of "in-between" keys would seem to be one of your own invention, and a more precise definition would be required to give it meaning. Nevertheless, such a construct would be outside the realm of Tonality.

Answer (score 0):

Major keys will have M3, while minor keys will have m3. How can there be anything in between? Obviously all 12 (13 with F♯/G♭) major keys will contain M3, and minors m3, but there are also the modes to consider - Dorian of each will be considered minor, while Mixolydian will be major.

So, only using 12tet, there are no other sorts of 'key' - except perhaps Locrian - which for most is not considered a key, as it's pretty unstable.

Keys and scales are often conflated - is that what's happening here?

Comment: No, I am not confusing Keys and Scales. I understand Keys, Key Signatures and The Circle Of Fifths might be used in only Western Music, but I am trying to apply Keys, Key Signatures and The Circle Of Fifths to Eastern Music which uses Microtonal Intervals, (for which that fastidious type of music is known as Microtonal Music, and also for which The Circle Of Fifths would convert into The Circle Of Thirds). That is basically my goal in this entire post. Just as The Circle Of Fifths is an abbreviation for The Circle Of Perfect Fifths, The Circle Of Thirds is also an abbreviation for

Comment: The Circle Of Neutral Thirds.

Comment: Although a Neutral Third is not an interval in Western Music, it IS an interval in Eastern Microtonal Music. If someone on Music Stack Exchange can COMPLETELY map out The Circle Of Neutral Thirds for Eastern Microtonal Music, that would be EXTREMELY useful for me.

Comment: I can't see how the two can be aligned. To me it's chalk and cheese. The set of 'rules' for one can't work for the other. Like playing cricket, using the rules of snooker, or tennis.

Comment: @DaveLittle Circle of neutral thirds? You mean something like C Eb/2 G Bb/2 D F#/2 A C#/2 E etc. (b/2 and #/2 meaning quarter tones)? That has nothing to do with your question? And for some reason you're not able to count this on your fingers yourself?

Comment: @Divizna Yes, that is precisely what I refer to as The Circle Of Thirds. It actually does have something to do with my question because my question is asking about all Keys that are NEITHER minor NOR Major. I could count them on my own, but I would prefer for someone whom is familiar with 24TET to count them all instead, as I, myself, am familiar with only 12TET.

Comment: @DaveLittle I'm not familiar with 24TET in the least. I'm just able to count to three and a half. Hopefully, so are you. It takes just a minute to go through the whole circle.

Comment: @DaveLittle Microtonality involved an entirely separate theory that has no concept of major and minor.

Comment: @DaveLittle the circle of fifths (or of any interval) describes what roots are available for chords or for keys.  The intervals that are available to form chords or scales based on any root may or may not be related to the circle of fifths.  For example, you could use 12-tone equally tempered intervals for chord roots, which is equivalent to using elements of the 12-tone-equal-temperament circle of fifths, yet tune the other elements of the chords using just intonation or indeed with 24-tone equally tempered neutral thirds.  Similarly, you can choose any one of the 24 tones from 24-tone...

Comment: @DaveLittle ...equal temperament and use that as the root of a triad comprising a major third and perfect fifth, a neutral third and perfect fifth, or a minor third and a perfect fifth, among many others.  You can find music that fits the modern conception of major and minor keys in the early Renaissance, before the 12-tone keyboard had come into existence, before closing the circle of fifths was a problem anyone had to deal with.  In other words, major and minor tonality can exist without the circle of fifths; similarly, the circle of neutral thirds will say little about "neutral" tonality.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the creators of MuseScore took the effort to program the possibility, the idea of having quarter tones in the key signature is apparently not unthinkable. However, these would very much be **non-standard** keys. It's entirely possible that a customary term specifically for "key with a neutral third" is not even coined. (But I suppose if you find the category meaningful, "neutral-third key" would work. **Not** "neutral key", as that already means [something else](https://usermanuals.finalemusic.com/Finale2012Win/Content/Finale/Neutral_key.htm).)

By the way, there doesn't seem to be such a thing as a "diminished key". Trying to look for it only finds me diminished chords.

Comment: Let’s say, for example, the ENTIRE piece is directly BETWEEN the Key of b minor and the Key of D Major. It does NOT Modulate. It is only SIMULTANEOUSLY BOTH Major and minor throughout the ENTIRE piece, and also WITHOUT switching between Major and minor. What Key would you say the piece is in?

Comment: @DaveLittle All this time you've been talking about neutral thirds in eastern music. Now you pull out a hypothetical song in standard two sharps key, no quarter tones anywhere, that you can't decide if it's in D major or B minor or A mixolydian or what. Which is something completely different (and without quarter tones, I guarantee there can't be a neutral third). Do you even KNOW what you're asking about?

Comment: @DaveLittle It would not be in a key. An example of this would be Satie's *Gymnopedie* #1, which is in both D major and D minor, but not really in either. The key signature, however, is typically given as D major, even though the piece ends in D minor, and it's not actually "in" either key — it's modal.

Comment: @Aaron Okay, but I’ve read everything about Modes and nothing suggests that ANY Mode is BOTH minor AND Major. I’m just looking for a phrase, that is completely accurate in Music Theory, to describe a piece being SIMULTANEOUSLY BOTH Major AND minor. In the case of Parallel Keys, (eg: SIMULTANEOUSLY BOTH D Major and d minor), I would describe the piece as being in the Key of D Neutral; however, I am not sure what to describe it as in the case of Relative Keys, (eg: SIMULTANEOUSLY BOTH D Major AND b minor).

Comment: @DaveLittle As I said in my post, Major and Minor are unique to Tonal theory, and Tonal theory does not recognize the kind of music you're describing. You could just call it D/B Major-Minor, which would be perfectly descriptive. However, to be "in a key", by definition, means that there is one central tone that serves as the single point of tonal stability — called "the tonic". The theory of Tonality does not allow for a piece with two tonics.

Comment: It actually can allow for a piece with 2 Tonics, though, simply by using Dyads rather than by using Single Notes.

Comment: @DaveLittle - when one sees the key sig. of 2#, one instinctively expects the piece to be in Dmajor and/or Bm, with often a 'modulation' between the two. In fact there are many pieces which move seamlessly twixt the two, so there's no knowing which actual key it's in. And one goes with the flow...

Comment: @DaveLittle Tonality requires exactly one tonic. A dyad would be analyzed to determine which of the two pitches functions as the unique tonic. If the answer is "neither", then the music is non-Tonal. Again, please add these details to your original post. They significantly impact its meaning.

Comment: That Finale has used "neutral key" to mean something does not imply that others should avoid using it to mean something else.  It is [by no means a standard term](https://www.dolmetsch.com/defsn.htm).

Comment: @DaveLittle "What Key would you say the piece is in?": Instead of speaking abstractly about hypothetical pieces perhaps it would be more helpful to speak about actual music. Post a link to a piece that illustrates what you're asking about so we can hear it. One problem with abstract descriptions of music is that they are vague and ambiguous. You may describe what you hear as "simultaneously major and minor" while someone else may call it a "blue note." People may assume that they understand what you're referring to when in fact you are referring to something else. An example would avoid this.